# Export group summary to CSV

Tags: r, export-to-csv, summary

I am trying to make a CSV export of a group of summary stats generated with (similar to):

```
group_sum <- tapply(df$value, df$group, summary)
```

I tried using this to export the batch of summary stats:

```
write.csv(t(as.matrix(group_sum)), file="name.csv")
```

Although the output is written to a CSV. It is not properly organized. Row1 lists the group names and Row2 includes ALL of the summary stats for each group.

What I need is a header row that lists the types of stats generated (i.e., Min, 1st Qu., Median, Mean, 3rd Qu., Max) and each set of summary stats listed on a separate row below the header row (labeled with the group names in a separate column). Any thoughts on how I can generate the CSV output this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tapply()` function returns a list which `write.csv()` can't handle. Change the list to a matrix. You didn't give us any data, so I'll use the `iris` data set in R:

```
data(iris)
group_sum  <- do.call(rbind, tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, summary))
write.csv(group_sum, file="name.csv")
```

These functions are documented on their manual pages: `help(tapply)` (or just `?tapply`) and `help(write.csv)`.

Comment: Works great, thanks. Just need to transpose this output table to get the desired format